# Error in reading event log reside in remote system

Tags: c#, .net, event-log

How can i read event logs residing at a remote computer on the same network using System.Diagnostics.EventLog in .net. it works fine if i give my own (local) computer name. But i don't know how to pass the remote computer name.

```
 EventLog Logs = new EventLog("Application",".");
```

"." is local computer name. how can i access logs on computer with name "venus".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

EventLog Logs = new EventLog("Application","RemotePcMachineName");